# JDSL, the graph library - where is it?

Tags: java, graph

Can anyone locate JDSL, the java graph library? It used to be [here](http://www.cs.brown.edu/cgc/jdsl/download.html), but you can't actually download it, while http://www.jdsl.org/ (don't bother visiting) is just spam.

Ok, perhaps the project is dead, but still, anywhere I can find the binaries? Searched high and low but no lack.

Comment: Have you tried emailing the contact email listed on the page you linked to? (`jdsl@cs.brown.edu`)

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned, though not sure if anyone is still behind that account. But surely someone must have downloaded it and it should be somewhere (I know I did, though years ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#zUxjQd0RIAY/trunk/jdsl/core/api/HashComparator.java&q=jdsl%20lang%3ajava&d=4) looks like the source for the core package (but not the graph package)...([more relevant results](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&sa=N&q=jdsl++lang%3ajava&ct=rr&cs_r=lang%3ajava)).

[The binaries are in the central Maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jdsl/jdsl) (but need to be [disassembled](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/)).

Comment: Great, thanks, the maven repository didn't turn high up in the results I got. Also, the accidental ambiguity of "jdsl" (a Sun component was named like this) didn't help. I was interested in the binary.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/implement/jdsl/implement.shtml

For anyone interested in the source to this library (as I was) this page has a link to download it.